# Apache is guessing the extension

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

When i go to /index/test i get /index.php/test. I would like to be able to mod rewrite from /index/page1 to /index.php?page=1 but even without any .htaccess file i get the index file without the variale.

It seems that my server is set to guess the extension and get the file if it exists. Is a Mac os X Server 10.6 with standard configuration (apache2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I found that multiviews was set by default in `/etc/apache2/sites/0001_any_80_[mydomain].conf`

Just change `+MultiViews` to `-MultiViews` in:

```
Options All -Includes -ExecCGI -Indexes +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called [`mod_speling`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) that could also be the culprit